# C Program compiles, but fails at runtime (too big of an array?). And 'checklist' suggestions?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm writing a program to look for the longest Collatz sequence starting under 1,000,000.

I was really proud of this code, it seemed so efficient and clean and well written... until I tried to run it. After a little debugging to get it to compile, I found that when I run the program, it crashes.

I have used both

```
int array[1000000];
```

and

```
int *array;
array = (int*)calloc(s, sizeof(int));
```

(where `s=1000000`)

to declare an array of 1,000,000 spaces.

So part A) of my question: Is it ridiculous or possible to declare an array of that size?

and part B) of my question: This is used for a 'checklist' of sorts, checking which numbers have already been seen. Is there a simpler or better or just different method of 'checking off' numbers that I should be using instead?

the code is as follows:

```
// This is a program to find the longest Collatz sequence starting under 1,000,000

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

// Collatz sequence: IF EVEN n/2  ::  IF ODD 3n+1

//define ints
int i;
int n; 
int c; // counter of sequence length
int longestsequence = 0;
int beststart;
int s = 1000000; //size of array

//define int array
    //int array[999999];

//define array using calloc
//define pointer for calloc int array
int *array; 
// do your calloc thing
array = (int*)calloc(s, sizeof(int)); // allocates 1,000,000 spots (s) of size "int" to array "array"

//fill array
for(i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) 
{
    array[i] = i;
}

for(i = 999999; i > 500000; i--)
{
    if(array[i] == 0) // skip if number has already been seen
        goto done;

    n = i;
    c = 0;

    //TEST
    printf("Current starting number is: %d\n", i);
    //TEST

    while(n != 4) // run and count collatz sequence
    {

        //TEST
        //printf("test1\n");
        //TEST

        if(n % 2 == 0) // EVEN
            n = n/2;
        else           // ODD
            n = 3 * n + 1;

        //TEST
        //printf("test2\n");
        //TEST

        c++;

        //TEST
        //printf("test3\n");
        //TEST

        if(n < 1000000 && array[n] != 0) // makes note of used numbers under 1000000
            array[n] = 0;

        //TEST
        //printf("test4\n");
        //TEST

    }

    if(longestsequence < c)
    {
        longestsequence = c;
        beststart = i;
        //TEST
        printf("Current best start is: %d\n", beststart);
        //TEST
    }

    done:
}

printf("the starting number that produces the longest Collatz sequence is...\n");
printf("%d\n", beststart);


getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any and all help and suggestions! Links to helpful sources are always appreciated.

---

UPDATE!

1.My code now looks like this^^^^

and

2.The program runs, and then mysteriously stops at `i` value `999167`

Comment: The line `goto done;` could be changed into `continue;` instead.

Comment: Don't do it. http://xkcd.com/710/

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i = 999999; i > 4; i++)
```

You easily go beyond array boundary here. I guess what you meant was

```
for(i = 999999; i > 4; --i)
                //     ^^^
```

Also, as in your implementation, 1 million element is not enough.

Take `n == 999999` as example. In the 1st step, you compute `3 * n + 1`, which is obviously way larger than 1000000. A simple solution would be change

```
    if(array[n-1] != 0) // makes note of used numbers
        array[n-1] = 0;
```

into

```
    if(n < s && array[n-1] != 0) // makes note of used numbers
        array[n-1] = 0;
```

which just disables result lookup when `n` is over array boundary.

Comment: Good catch! Though I still get the same runtime error. The windows, "The program has stopped working, windows will check for solutions".

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple linked list of numbers, which will reduce the memory requirements at the expense of "long" search times. I've always noticed a bit of repetition:

```
1
2 → 1 (already seen in 1, so link to the existing 1)
3 → 5 → 16 → 8 → 4 → 2 (already seen in 2, so link to the existing 2)
4 (link to existing after 8)
5 (link to existing after 5)
etc.
```

You would have a number A and possibly one more number B link to a number N for some numbers, but N would only link to one number C. For example:

```
 A ->  N -> C
 3 -> 10 -> 5
20 -> 10 -> 5
 B ->  N -> C
```

Of course, you could optimize it by storing a length of the list and an extra pointer containing the next adjacent number, allowing you to implement a binary search using that length as a guide.

However, if you're only looking for the longest sequence length instead of the sequence itself, why aren't you merely storing the longest length found and comparing it to the length of the current sequence? Storing the numbers only for calculating the length seems like overkill. Something like the following pseudocode:

```
Longest := 0

For N = 1 To 1000000
    Length := 1
    X := N

    While X != 1
        Length := Length + 1

        If IsEven(X) Then
            X := 3 * X + 1
        Else
            X := X / 2
        End If
    End While

    If Length > Longest Then
        Longest := Length
    End If
End For
Print("Longest sequence less than 1000000 is: ", Longest)
```

Comment: I thought about this type of binary search method. My issue with it, however, is that as you go from 1 backwards, the possibilities often double. I struggled to find a way to do this while narrowing possibilities instead of increasing. 

My list is to reduce the iterations necessary. If I have already encountered a number, I must have started with a higher number, and it's following sequence will always be the same, meaning it wasn't the longest. But your pseudocode is essentially what I started with. My array was supposed to make it run faster. 

By the way, thank you for your answer! Quality

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
        n = 3 * n + 1;
```

ends up setting the value of `n` to be higher than the valid index. The highest valid index is `999999`. You have to make sure that `n` is less than or equal to `1000000` before you access the array in:

```
     if(array[n-1] != 0) // makes note of used numbers
        array[n-1] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't check the array index `[n-1]` within the while loop to ensure it doesn't exceed the array bounds of 1,000,000. For example, in your first loop `i = 999,999` which makes `n = 999999*3+1 = 2,999,998'.

Solution is to make sure `n` doesn't exceed your array size.